# how to register div click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to register the clickevent for my div. If I place the iframe inside the div it wont work. If it is outside it will work. How can I get it working when the iframe is inside the div?

html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #mydiv
        {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            var clicks = 0;
            $('#mydiv').bind('click', function (e) {
                clicks++;
                $("#numberclicks").html(clicks);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="numberclicks"></span>
        <div id="mydiv">
            <iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.jquery.com" width="300" height="300" />
        </div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe is a totally differente DOM document, that is why, when you click on the DIV, the browser is actually rendering the clicks on the iframe content, you can put an empty div over the iframe to mimic that, that would be something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #mydiv
        {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        #clickerDiv 
        {
            height: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            var clicks = 0;
            $('#mydiv').bind('click', function (e) {
                clicks++;
                $("#numberclicks").html(clicks);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="numberclicks">0</span>
        <div id="mydiv">
            <div id="clickerDiv"></div>
            <iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.jquery.com" width="300" height="300" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can link the click event to the phantom div, or even to the main div container!

Comment: ok it counts the clicks but all the links within the Iframe do not work now? I would like both!

Comment: Sorry, you can´t have both things, or you should read that directly on the ifram, do you have acces to the iframe Source?

Answer (score 2):

The iframe is swallowing the click events for the div as its a cross site scripting thing, what you can do is put a div over top of the iframe using z-index and collect clicks from the upper div.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the actual click events come to the content of `iframe`, which is a whole different document. In order to handle those, you have to attach to that document's click event.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are mostly correct -- the IFRAME creates a new window object.  You are wiring into the "#mydiv" elements in the parent window, not your IFRAME's window.  When a click event  occurs in a DIV, it will "bubble" up through the DOM tree.  Provided that the event is not "stopped" from bubbling, you could catch and handle the event in any of the DIV's parent elements.  However, because it is in an IFRAME, it will stop bubbling at the document level and will not continue to bubble in the parent frame.

Now, if the IFRAME were on the same domain as your parent frame, you could access the elements of that document and wire-up your event handler to those elements.  However, you appear to be working across domains which violates the "Same Origin Policy": http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_DOM_access